# Accessing an existing telegram bot

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot

I have an existing bot on telegram. It sends me a notice whenever a button is pressed on my Arduino. What I'm trying to do now is use python to access the information on the bot. ie send notice to my python script instead of phone. I know telegram has an API but even with my Arduino running, I just keep getting 404 error when accessing the API via a browser. I'm new to using APIs and was wondering if there is something I'm misunderstanding about the telegram API.

Below is my Arduino code:

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClientSecure.h>
#include <TelegramBot.h>


#define LED 1
// Initialize Wifi connection to the router
const char* ssid     = "SSID";
const char* password = "Password";


// Initialize Telegram BOT
const char BotToken[] = "BOT_TOKEN";

WiFiClientSecure net_ssl;
TelegramBot bot (BotToken, net_ssl);

 // the number of the LED pin  
void setup() 
{  
 Serial.begin(115200);  
 while (!Serial) {}  //Start running when the serial is open 
 delay(3000);  
 // attempt to connect to Wifi network:  
 Serial.print("Connecting Wifi: ");  
 Serial.println(ssid);  
 while (WiFi.begin(ssid, password) != WL_CONNECTED) {  
   Serial.print(".");  
   delay(500);  
     }  
 Serial.println("");  
 Serial.println("WiFi connected");  
 bot.begin();  
 pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);  
}  
void loop() 
{  
 message m = bot.getUpdates(); // Read new messages  
 if (m.text.equals("on")) 
       {  
   digitalWrite(LED, 1);   
   bot.sendMessage(m.chat_id, "The Led is now ON");  
 }  
 else if (m.text.equals("off")) 
       {  
   digitalWrite(LED, 0);   
   bot.sendMessage(m.chat_id, "The Led is now OFF");  
 }  
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

UPDATE:
I am able to use the getme method, but when using the sendMessage method, I get a 403 error, saying "bot can't send messages to bots".